# flexigrid not working with html table

Tags: flexigrid

Need a help in loading up flexigrid for a HTML Table. I have the below piece of code and could not get flexigrid loaded when open up this html file in browsers(Tried IE, firefox, chrome). Please help in getting this work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Phone Directory</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/flexigrid.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/flexigrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.flexme').flexigrid();
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="flexme">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="100">Col 1</th>
                <th width="100">Col 2</th>
                <th width="100">Col 3 is a long header name</th>
                <th width="300">Col 4</th>

            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>This is data 1</td>
                <td>This is data 2</td>
                <td>This is data 3</td>

                <td>This is data 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>This is data 1</td>
                <td>This is data 2</td>
                <td>This is data 3</td>
                <td>This is data 4</td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try with latest jquery version

Answer (score 2):

The document ready function is missing.

Replace the line `$('.flexme').flexigrid();` with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#flexme').flexigrid();
});
```